# Properties of The Number 137

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The number $137$ is a prime number.One of the permutation of $137$ is $173$, which is a prime number. The summation of $137$ digits is $11$ which is again a prime number!

My question: Is there a name for this type of numbers?

There are some other Properties for $137$ in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/137_(number)). I found another Properties such that
$137=2^7+2^3+1$ or the only way to write the number $137$ as a summation of  two square numbers is $137=4^2+11^2$.

thanks for your advice and suggestions.

**Edit:**
After reading comments and answers, I want to suggest a definition for such numbers like $137$. At first, I want to excuse me for this Venture that I want to make a definition. In the following definition, we suppose that the number one is a prime number.

> **Definition:** We call a prime number like $p$,  $\color{red}{\text{Sum and Permutation Prime}}$ of order $i\geq 1$ or in abbreviation *SPP* of order $i\geq 1$ if and only if

- The summation of digits of $p$ be prime.
- There is a number like $i\geq 1$, where all permutation of  the $p$ of length $i$ be prime numbers.

If the last condition holds for $1\leq i \leq L(p)$, where $L(p)$ is the length of prime number $p$, we call the prime number $p$, SPP with full order.
The last condition is because of one of the answers that said all permutation of $137$ of length two are prime numbers.

The number $113$ is a  SPP numbers with full order but $137$ is not SPP with full order because $371$,$713$ and $731$ are not prime numbers. In fact $137$ is a SPP number of orders $1$ and $2$.

The SPP numbers of order ($\geq2$), do not have prime numbers $2$ and $5$ in their digits and just are consist of numbers $1$, $3$, $7$ and $9$.

Thanks again for all nice comments and beautiful answers.

Comment: Anecdotic numbers ?

Comment: Maybe $137$ is the *smallest uninteresting* number ?

Comment: These are just numerical coincidences, and have nothing to do with mathematics.

Comment: Today I was working with windows server 2012 and when i wanted to setup [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), I saw for infinite time, DHCP use $137$ years. This was my motivate for this question.

Comment: I said with my self, maybe the $137$ has the story like [Taxicab number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number).

Comment: Out of the $3$ properties of $137$ that you've mentioned, $2$ properties hold **only** because you're using decimal (base-$10$) representation. It doesn't mean that they do not hold in **any** other base. But it sure means that they do not hold in **every** other base. So there is nothing generally interesting about this combination of properties of $137$. You're only saying: "$1\cdot10^2+3\cdot10^1+7\cdot10^0$, $7\cdot10^2+3\cdot10^1+1\cdot10^0$ and $1+3+7$ are all prime numbers".

Comment: According to Eddington, at least, it's the reciprocal of the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant)

Comment: $137$ indeed has to do with the taxicab number $1729$. The digit squares are $1^2+7^2+2^2+9^2=135$; then add $2$ form the windows server $2012$ and we get $137$ (well, or take the next prime after $135$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde my Colleague said, $137$ is an nonsense number, but I told him there are lots of principles in this number.

Comment: These snarky comments made my day. Thanks

Comment: According to your definition, $137$ is not SPS: It fails condition 2 because $1$ is not prime.

Comment: @celtschk you right. I edit my definition and suppose one is a prime number. Thanks

Comment: Note that you can skip the uniqueness in your square condition. If a prime $p$ can be written as a sum of two squares (i.e. if $p = 1 \pmod{4}$ or $p=2$) then there is exactly one way to do it. In particular this means that you can rephrase the condition as $p$ should be $1$ modulo $4$ (or $p=2$).

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck I remove this condition that you mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no name for that property. If Sloane's OEIS listed these numbers, it would probably just call them "Prime numbers such that the digits can be permuted to form another prime number and the sum of digits is also prime."

The most relevant search result I could find is http://oeis.org/A104736 "Numbers $n$ such that $n$ and the digital sums of $n$ and $n$-th prime are primes." But it doesn't say anything about permutations of digits.

The OEIS does list numbers called "absolute primes" or "permutable primes," but to be considered one of those, *every* permutation of the base $10$ digits must give another prime. $137$ fails this test because $371 = 7 \times 53$.

I suggest you figure out what the first hundred or so prime numbers of this sort are and ask the Editors of Sloane's OEIS to add a listing for it.

Comment: I appreciate your answering my question.

Answer (score 3):

Another property: Any combination of 2 digits from 137 is also prime (13,17,31,37,71,73).

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no name for a such property.

For the *first sight* it may be very interesting how special is the number `137`. But there a *many other numbers* with *many other interesting properties*, so from general point of view the number 137 is only a *drop in the ocean*.

Such numbers are chiefly for non-mathematician who think about some mystical message related to them.

Comment: Nice expression " 137 is a drop in the ocean". Thanks